# Magento 2.4.4: How to get Configurable child product id using Swatch option

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, swatches, magento24

How can I get the child product Id of Configurable product on selecting swatch option. I have used following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
            selpro();
        });
    });
    function selpro () {
        var selected_options = {};
        jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){


            var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('data-attribute-id');
            var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('data-option-selected');
            if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
            selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
        });
        var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
        
        var found_ids = [];
        jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
            var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
                return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
            }
            if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
                found_ids.push(product_id);
            }
        });
        if (found_ids.length) {
            var selected_product_id = found_ids[0];
            jQuery('.myli').css('display','none');
            jQuery('#div'+selected_product_id).toggle();
        }
    }
});
```

Following this line give Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')

jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your custom js code in document.ready

```
<script>
    require([
    'jquery'
    ], function () {
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
         //add your code here
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Prashant thanks for your reply I have updated my code in question now you can check